# Create service/application that runs before another application is launched

Tags: c#, windows-7

I am looking to write an application that does *stuff* before any other executable is ran. Doing the *stuff* is something I am fairly sure I can teach myself or at least I know what to research to accomplish it. I am not sure on how I can configure windows to run an application (app1) prior to other applications running or, since that creates an infinite loop if app1 triggers itself, pass information about a soon to be launched application to an already running windows service.

My goal for the *stuff* is to change the default sound device prior to launching an application automatically. I have two sound devices, USB headphones and speakers. From experience, if the headphones are the default sound device prior to launching an application, that application will use the headphones as its sound output even if the default changes later.

So the question is, is there any way I can configure Windows 7 to call a service/application prior to launching any other executable?

Comment: It would be a pretty huge security hole in Windows itself if this was possible. Every malware author on the planet would just configure systems to have Windows automatically launch their malware prior to launching any other executable.

Comment: I can see it being a security hole, but my memory is that I have seen virus's do that where running any exe launches the virus. I believe they modify HKLM\Software\CLASSES\exefile\shell\open\command and it's ilk to do so, I was looking for a more legitimate way and I'm not sure if the application would have knowledge of the launched application. I also thought some AntiVirus' scanned exe's on launch and prevented launching applications if the scan failed or wasn't on a whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing. I think you're trying to execute some code every time a process starts (not execute some code once before ANY processes start at all on the machine). If that's correct, you're in luck. You can inject your own DLL into every process, and your DLL will run before the main/WinMain of the executable. See [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/197571) for information.

Generally speaking, this concept is known as a [rootkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit). Please note that many virus scanners and system cleanup utilities will detect this and may flag your application as a virus or malware. You should carefully consider whether or not this is something you truly need to do.

[Here's some info](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/what-happens-when-a-dll-is-added-to-appinit-dll) on using these in 32/64-bit processes.